# A term for unreasonable price

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-request, verbs

For example:

> The mangos’ price was 35 ruppes for 1 K.g., but they charged me 100 ruppes for that.

> I stayed in a hotel, but they overcharged me with a trick because I was new there.

That’s they deceivingly took money from me too much because I was new there

Comment: they ripped me off

Comment: Son Nguyen, thanks!

Comment: "They [**fleeced**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fleece) me" (verb¹).

Answer (score 4):

A popular noun is "rip-off".

> Clerk: 1kg of mangos is 100 USD! 
> Customer A: That's a rip-off!
> Customer B: This store is a rip-off!

... and the verb is "to rip someone off".

> That store ripped me off!